# Force directory to be created in Python

Tags: python

I am running Python with MPI on a supercomputing cluster. I am getting strange nondeterministic behavior that I think is a result of I/O complications that are not present on the single machines I'm used to working with.

One of the things my code does is to create directories using `os.makedirs` somewhat frequently. I know also that I generally should not write small amounts of data to the filesystem-- this can end up with the data getting stuck in some buffer and not written for a long time. I suspect this may be happening with my directory creation calls, and then later code tries to write to files inside the directory before it exists. Two questions:

- is creating a new directory effectively the same thing as writing a small amount of data?
- When forcing data to be written, I use `flush` and `os.fsync`. These require a file object. Is there an equivalent to make sure the directory has been created?

Comment: `while not os.path.isdir(target): # wait or retry`?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new directory is effectively the same as writing small amount of data. It adds an inode.

The only way mkdir (or os.mkdirs) should fail is if the directory exists - otherwise the directory will always be created. In terms of the data being buffered - it's unlikely that this would happen - even journaled filesystems will sync out pretty regularly.

If you're having non-deterministic behavior, just wrap your directory creation / writing a file into that directory inside a try / except / finally that makes a few efforts? But really - the need for such code hints at something much more sinister and is likely a bigger issue.